# SwiftUI: How to parse String Array into text

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I've tried following [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/creating-views-in-a-loop) and [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-views-in-a-loop-using-foreach) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array), but I'm having issues getting the data from a string array.

I have my state set as

```
 businessHours = : [
    "Monday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
    "Tuesday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
    "Wednesday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
    "Thursday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
    "Friday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
    "Saturday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
    "Sunday: Closed"
 ]
```

This only gets me the first element from the array

```
ForEach(businessHours.indices) {
    Text(self.businessHours[$0])
}
```

This fails

```
ForEach(businessHours.indices) {
    Text(self.businessHours)
}
```

This works in the console

```
for businesshour in businessHours {
print("Hours: \(businesshour).")
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm not going to be able to do this without providing my API key

Comment: You may use the JSON response you receive from the server. No need for the API key.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler way..

When you have an array where the values are separated by ", " you can divide the array with this comma symbol

For Example: I have a user model with food. Food is an array, which looks similar like this:

```
user.food = ["Banana", "Strawberry", "Apple"]
```

You noticed: Every item is separated by the comma.

Now you can simply use

```
Text(user.food.joined(separator: ", "))
   .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
   .padding()
```

Et voilá :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo that works. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image]

```
struct DemoView: View {
    let businessHours = [
         "Monday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
         "Tuesday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
         "Wednesday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
         "Thursday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
         "Friday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
         "Saturday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
         "Sunday: Closed"
     ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(businessHours.indices) {
                 Text(self.businessHours[$0])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh this is interesting.  I did some more testing and that does work, but if the data is dumped into a `State` such as ` @State var businessHours = []` from an API call I get my original behavior.  When I print `businessHours` I get the following in the console `["Monday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM", "Tuesday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM", "Wednesday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM", "Thursday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM", "Friday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM", "Saturday: 7:00 AM – 7:00 PM", "Sunday: Closed"]`

Comment: Well... then I assume the issue is in the code you assign values from API to state.

Comment: Sorry that isn't making sense since when I print `businessHours` to the console all the data is present, but it's only taking the first index.

Comment: I also found that if I use `Text("\(businessHours)" as String)` the data is dumped into text

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
(0..<businessHours.count, id: \.self) { index in
       Text(self.businessHours[index])
}
```